# Is it possible to replace the iOS incoming call screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Instead of showing the default "incoming call" screen, I would like to show my own screen (from my app) whenever I receive a call on my iPhone.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer; no.

iOS doesn't allow you to take over that functionality.

At least not "out of the box".

Comment: What would be the long answer? Is there a work-around? I really really need to change the call screen, or at least add information to it. Is this possible at all?

Comment: So how come Messenger and Whatsapp customize buttons when receiving a call?