# Custom incoming call screen like Truecaller IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

Is it possible to have a functionality to show customized incoming call screen when an incoming call arrives just like **truecaller app** does.

I have referred [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223135/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-ios-incoming-call-screen), which says its not possible.

I wonder how `truecaller` show a `custom view`. 
Any idea regarding the same would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to replace default iOS call screen. You can design your custom dial pad but to perform a real call you have to call iOS dial feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **"NO"**, you can't customise the incoming call screen.

As for Truecaller, i think you are mistaken to get the concept.I used to think the same and found the below objective while exploring my Addressbook.

Truecaller never shows a custom view, instead true caller store its custom image (Red View with image ("Identified by truecaller") as contact in your address book.
This will work similar to the other contact you store in your contacts with their image.
[image]

Hope this helps you to work around.